# Rendering HTML securely without HTML Encoding

Tags: html, security, wysiwyg, html-encode

Assume you want to allow non-technical users to control content that appears on a public site/app.  If the content is merely text, then you can HTML encode the text when you display it to prevent malicious scripts from being executed should they get into your database.

What options are available to prevent this scenario when you want to display the data as HTML (i.e. when the data is entered through a WYSIWYG editor)?  Am I going to have to clean the data with a blacklist every time I want to display it?

Also, assume that the data has already been compromised.  I am really looking for ways to limit damage from this sort of attack when HTML encoding is not an option.

For my purposes, the site is running ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am utilizing jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always whitelist elements and attribute names instead of blacklisting.  [.NET HTML whitelisting (anti-xss/Cross Site Scripting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224049/net-html-whitelisting-anti-xss-cross-site-scripting) discusses whitelisting HTML sanitizers for .NET.

Other options include loading the content in an iframe in a throwaway domain, but this will not stop the content from performing certain kinds of attacks -- redirecting to a phishing page, starting downloads of malware, scanning the local network, exploiting XSRF vulnerabilities using the user's credentials, etc.

Comment: I went with Microsoft's AntiXSS library - very simple to use.  I was actually surprised to hear that the default HTML encode is a blacklist method?  Anyway - thanks for directing me towards whitelisting (I was aware of the concept - just didn't think to apply it towards HTML).

Comment: "the default HTML encode is a blacklist method?": because the char set is limited, it is blacklisting and whitelisting at the same time. Say the charset is "abcd" If you say "chars a and b are disallowed" or "c and d are allowed" is the same.

Comment: @usr.  To be clear, I was only talking about whitelisting in the context of element and attribute names.  Based on some definitions, you are right, there is no distinction between blacklisting and whitelisting when it comes to a finite set.  But some define whitelisting as allowing only those things you can prove safe, and blacklisting as disallowing those things you can prove harmful.  By those definitions, there can be a material difference between blacklisting and whitelisting elements of a finite set.